# Bash how to insert into array if the array does not contain the value within if statement

Tags: bash

I have a function to check if something is in an array:

```
function inArray() {
    local val="$1"
    shift
    local array=("$@")
    for i in "${array[@]}"; do
        if [ "${i}" == "${val}" ]; then
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}
```

And an if statement to try to insert values into `noDupe` only if it doesn't already have that value:

```
noDupe=()
values=("test" "test" "test2")
for value in ${values[@]}; do
    if [ $(inArray "${value}" "${values[@]}") -eq 1 ]; then
        noDupe+="{value}"
    fi
done
```

My current error is that `-eq` expects a unary operator. I've tried changing it to a `==` but that's just for strings and not the `0`s and `1`s my function is returning. How can I get the if statement to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is  using return values, but you're trying to use it as it if the return values were printed. The correct usage for "if the exit status is non-zero" simplifies to

```sh
if ! inArray "${value}" "${values[@]}"; then
```

---

Side note: the error you're getting is not that `-eq` expects a unary operator, it's

```
bash: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

meaning that `[` expected a unary operator, but instead it got `-eq`, a binary operator. This is because your command substitution is unquoted, and when the command returns nothing, your test becomes

```sh
[ -eq 1 ]
```

With proper quoting,

```sh
[ "$(inArray "${value}" "${values[@]}")" -eq 1 ]
```

the test would complain that it expects an integer expression (but gets the empty string instead), because it expands to

```sh
[ "" -eq 1 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The array search function can become a bottleneck if the array length is large. As an alternative consider using bash associative array. It will simplify the code, and speed up execution - reducing the complexity from O(n^2) to O(n log n).

The no-dup logic can be implemented without having to write the inArrayfunction.

```
declare -A v_temp
values=("test" "test" "test2")
for value in ${values[@]}; do
    v_temp[$value]=1
done
noDupe=(${!v_temp[@]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this method using `$BASH_REMATCH`:

```
inArray () {
    re="_S_$1 | $1 | ${1}_E_"
    [[ "_S_${array[@]}_E_" =~ $re ]] && return 0 || return 1
}
```

And array name could be also send as arg to this function:

```
inArray () {
    name="$1[@]"
    re="_S_$2 | $2 | ${2}_E_"
    [[ "_S_${!name}_E_" =~ $re ]] && return 0 || return 1
}
```